# R: How to replace all rows in a group with a value from first row in a df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace, group-by

I have a df, and I would like to replace all the rows in a group with the value from the first instance/row pr group.

So eg. for the mtcars dataset, I would like for each group of carb to create a new variable carb_1, that replaces all values in the column for carb with the value from qsec with the first row for carb (eg. 18.61 for carb==1):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  arrange(carb, qsec)
```

I have tried with a dplyr combo of mutate and top_n, but it does not provide the right results:

```
mtcars %>%
   group_by(carb)%>%
   mutate(carb_1 = top_n(mtcars, 1,qsec ))

#or

mtcars %>%
   group_by(carb)%>%
   mutate(carb_1 = top_n(mtcars, 1,carb))
```

The expected results are something like this for carb==1, for all rows with carb==2: 16.70  and so on...

```
df_expected <- mtcars
df_expected$carb_1 <- ifelse(df_expected$carb==1, 18.61, df_expected$carb)
df_expected
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `mtcars %>% group_by(carb)%>% mutate(carb_1 = first(qsec))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `first` function in `dplyr`

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb)%>%
  mutate(carb_1 = first(qsec))
```

Though if you are ordering by `qsec` you could also just use `min`